# A synonym for Viral

Tags: synonyms

*Viral*,   meaning a contagious spreading  of word, saying, picture or song which reach a huge number of people through the Net, mainly via social networks, is now a very popular  term that is finding its way into traditional dictionaries. Can you think  a synonym or a word that suggest  the same concept.

Comment: Which dictionaries? 'Spreading like wildfire' is a more traditional expression. 'Big', 'mega' ... are/were often used to describe the thing that has spread.

Comment: Such things used to be called _crazes_ or _fads_. I wonder if we'll hear a future historian talking about the time hula hooping "went viral"?

Comment: *Viral* is perfectly fine. No need to look for a synonym when you already have the best word for the situation.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth, Viral in the definition given above can be found here for instance:http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/viral?q=viral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that something has gone **viral** on the Internet, we could probably say that something is **trending** or **popular**. **Viral** is one of the best words to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Something has gone viral
Something is spreading fast.
Something is gaining **prominence**.
**Something is trending.**
Something is accelerating.
Something is gaining wide acceptance.
Something is becoming **prominent**.
Something is becoming **popular**.

http://thesaurus.com/browse/Viral

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term **[infectious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/infectious)** which long [predates](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=infectious&searchmode=none) *viral* to mean

> Likely to spread or influence others in a rapid manner:
>   *her enthusiasm is infectious*

While it cannot simply be substituted in some constructions, such as

> *Enthusiasm for the song has gone viral!*

alternate constructions are possible

> *Enthusiasm for the song has become infectious!*

Answer (score 0):

Consider the idiom "[all the rage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rage?&o=100074&s=t)."

> all the rage: widely popular or in style.

E.g.

[Her move, widely criticized by rivals, has been effective in terms of popularity, as her picture is all the rage in the network.](http://m24digital.com/en/2011/09/06/scandal-at-miss-universe-colombia-representative-poses-without-underwear/)

Answer (score 0):

"contagious spread"
"promiscuous sharing"
"logarithmic growth"

Answer (score 0):

Specifically through the 'net, you can use *has become a meme*. Depends on your target audience, though - the word meme is not as widely known as "viral"

Answer (score -1):

**Epidemic** and **Pandemic** can be used synonymously but they are just not pretty in a business context. Nevertheless, I have heard the expression "taking on epidemic proportions".

Comment: epidemic and pandemic are specific to real diseases and cannot be applied to cat-videos

Comment: @msam Not necessarily: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epidemic

Comment: Correct @nxx. Epidemic is also used frequently in the context of incident management, business continuity planning and disaster recovery planning.

Comment: @nxx Good point. "epidemic proportions" aside since that is relating to the proportions, I had never before heard anything like "the little girl's giggles were epidemic" (would have said contagious)

Comment: @msam Ha! I didn't even see that example. It does seem odd. But yes, the point is that "epidemic" does have broader usage than just contexts of disease or moonstar's weighty examples.